# upgrade django2 to 3 DigitalOcean droplets missing css files

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I just install fresh image of django from DigitalOcean droplets marketplace and its work perfectly but its version 2 so I try to upgrade it to 3 and everything went fine except admin page missing 2 file

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (nav_sidebar.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (nav_sidebar.js, line 0)

Comment: try deleting the admin folder in the static and run `collectstatic` again. The static files may be remained from the version 2 and there seem to be some breaking changes in the admin page

Comment: I did but still same error and I check the static directory it has all missing file but I think its read from some where else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the nignx pointed path for admin static files to main python static path

Change it to django project static directory and thats fixing the problem